# Unconventional ways to light a fire

Tags: survival, fire-starting

In a survival situation, lets say post apocalyptic, what are some unconventional ways a campfire could be lit? Obviously there are the classic flint and steel, rod and bow, and of course matches. But what are creative non conventional ways to start a fire from things you might find in a post apocalyptic scenario?

One example i have heard would be with a battery, and a piece of foiled chewing gum wrapper seen [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-A-Lighter-Out-Of-Battery-Gum-Wrapper/)

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lists-of-ideas will almost never be complete, are hard to maintain, never have a single right answer, etc...

Comment: @Roflo Lists would be okay in a community wiki format

Comment: It's all good, i had looked for duplicates before posting, i think that this extends far beyond the scope of starting a fire with a battery, that was just an example, but whatever you guys think is best for the page.

Comment: Too bad.  This was an interesting question.

Comment: @Qudit I agree. I actually like it and I'm glad Nate included an answer. Still, SE sites work best in strict Q&A format.

Comment: @Roflo There are plenty of other SE sites that allow list style questions and I don't see them causing problems.  I for one, would have liked to see more answers.

Comment: @Qudit that's actually an interesting point: assuming we receive 2, 3, 5 more answers... which one would be the accepted answer? Nate already mentioned a lot in his own answer. If anything, Charlie is spot-on and this _might_ work as a community wiki answer.

Comment: @Roflo Whichever one the OP considers the most interesting.  Anyway, just because there might not be a clear best answer is a weak reason to close IMO.  It's hard to even say if that is true without actually seeing the answers.

Comment: 4 recent downvotes to the answer??? why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research i found a suitable answer to my own question. Feel free to add your own as well, i thought i would share as i found it rather interesting.

Taken from [Urbansurvivalsite.com](https://urbansurvivalsite.com/weirdest-ways-to-start-a-fire/)

> **Steel Wool and Battery**
>
> This is similar to the gum wrapper method. Just stretch the steel wool so it reaches the positive and negative terminals, and it will create enough energy to set the wool on fire. The easiest way is to use a 9V battery (like in the video below) because you can easily touch both terminals to the steel wool at the same time. But if all you have is a cylindrical battery such as a AA battery, you can use that as well.
>
> **Jumper Cables and a Car Battery**
>
> First, attach a set of jumper cables to your car battery. Then take the opposite ends and tap them together to create sparks. If you have plenty of dry tinder, you can use those sparks to get a fire started. It’s even easier if you have some steel wool. This method is somewhat dangerous since you risk blowing up your car battery, but it’s worth a try to avoid freezing.
>
> **Pencil and a Car Battery**
>
> If you don’t want to make sparks with your jumper cables, try this instead. Carve down two ends of a pencil until the lead is exposed, then attach your jumper cables to both ends of the pencil, making sure the jumper cables are touching the lead. Place the pencil on your tinder, then attach the other ends of the jumper cables to your car battery. Soon, the pencil will heat up and set your tinder on fire.
>
> **D Batteries and a Cell Phone Cord**
>
> First, take your charger cord and strip the ends so the wire is exposed. Hold two D batteries together, press one end of the cord to the bottom of one battery, then touch the wires on the other end of the cord to the top of the other battery. Have some tinder touching the top of the other battery also. The heat will cause the tinder to catch fire. This is a little tricky, but it works.
>
> **A Condom Filled With Water**
>
> Seriously. Just fill a condom with water until it’s the size of a small water balloon, then hold it at an angle that focuses the sunlight into a narrow beam. Focus the beam of sunlight onto some dried grass for a few minutes. This will cause the grass to heat and eventually start burning.
>
> **Urine and a Plastic Bag**
>
> It may sound far-fetched, but it works if you have plenty of sunlight. First, fill a plastic bag with urine. Alternatively, you can shape some plastic wrap into a bowl, put some urine in it, and wrap it up (as seen in the video below). A water bottle probably won’t work because you won’t be able to fill it enough to get the refraction you need. Once your urine-filled magnifying glass is ready, use it to focus a beam of sunlight on your tinder. Before long, it will catch fire.
>
> **Plastic Wrap and Water**
>
> Another way to use sunlight is to create an aqua lens. Stretch some plastic wrap across a frame of some sort and secure it in place with tape. Then pour water onto the plastic wrap until you have a bowl of water. If the sun is overhead, the aqua lens will form a beam of sunlight under which you can put your tinder. Before long, the tinder will catch fire.
>
> **A Light Bulb and Water**
>
> This one is fairly simple. Break off the bottom of a clear light bulb and remove everything inside it. Fill the light bulb with water and use it as an aqua lens to focus sunlight on a bundle of tinder. After a while, the tinder will start burning.
>
> **An Old TV Screen**
>
> If you have or can find an old big screen TV, take it apart and remove the giant Fresnel lens. Now simple angle the lens so a beam of sunlight is focused on your tinder. Before long, the tinder will catch fire. Warning: This method makes a very hot beam of sunlight. So hot, in fact, that it can boil a bottle of water. So don’t stick your hand in the sunbeam.
>
> **A Chunk of Ice**
>
> Yes, ice can also start a fire. It works the same way as the condom filled with water. Just angle the ice at your dried grass and let sun work its magic. You’ll want to wear gloves so your hands don’t get too cold. This method can take a bit, and you’ll need direct sunlight to do it, but it definitely works.
>
> **Chocolate and a Soda Can**
>
> Simply rub some chocolate on the bottom of an aluminum can, then polish it with a paper towel or cloth until it’s nice and shiny. After that, you can use it as a reflective tool to aim a beam of sunlight at your tinder. Before long, the tinder will catch fire. Then add wood to build a fire. If you don’t have any chocolate, use some toothpaste instead.
>
> **A Flashlight**
>
> Remove the top lens and pull out the reflective cone that the light bulb sits in. Place a bit of dried grass or dry moss where the bulb would normally sit, and place the cone in direct sunlight. The reflection of the sunlight will heat the tinder and cause it to start burning.
>
> **An Empty Lighter**
>
> An empty lighter may seem useless, but you can still use it to start a fire. Slowly grind the wheel of the lighter against a sheet of paper. After a minute or two, you’ll accumulate a small pile of flint dust. Now put some tinder on the dust, then use the lighter to throw a spark at it. The dust will catch the spark and set your tinder on fire.
>
> **Brake Fluid and Chlorine**
>
> Start with a small pile of powdered chlorine, pour some brake fluid on it, then quickly back away. After smoking for a few moments, the pile will burst into flames. Now throw some tinder and wood on the pile before the flames go out. Since there’s the possibility of an explosive effect, I recommend wearing safety goggles or averting your eyes. I would also do this on the ground instead of in a container since there’s no telling how the material in the container will react.